# SymBrowser_ModifyWindowOpenWithTarget Browser Error

Tags: reactjs, webkit, sentry

We are currently using Sentry Error Tracking Software to find javascript errors. We've been receiving the following error pretty consistently:

`Can't find variable: SymBrowser_ModifyWindowOpenWithTarget`

Seems to be occurring when viewing our react webapp through a Safari browser on iOS.

The issue is not specific to any version of iOS but seems to be mostly occurring on iOS version 11.4.1.

I've tried to reproduce the issue myself but have had no luck, and am curious if anyone has seen this issue before.

Comment: I'm seeing this too with a React app, only from iOS users. The string `SymBrowser_ModifyWindowOpenWithTarget` doesn't occur in the built files, so chances are it's some kind of browser extension.

Comment: Just one user for me in sentry:

browser.name: Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView
device: iPhone
device.family: iPhone
level: error
logger: javascript
os: iOS 15.4.1
os.name: iOS

Comment: We've also seen in logs similar "Can't find variable: SymBrowser_ModifyAnchorTagWithTarget at global code"

Answer (score 1):

One of our users is seeing this.  After [looking up the browser name](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235349/which-device-uses-mobile-safari-uiwebview-as-the-browser-name), it sounds like it's not Safari.  We don't plan on trying to figure out which third-party browser is causing sentry errors without user reports.

- browser.name: Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView
- device: iPhone
- device.family: iPhone
- level: error
- logger: javascript
- os: iOS 15.4.1
- os.name: iOS